# How to transform JSON value to Kafka message key with Debezium MongoDB Source Connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using the Debezium MongoDB Connector to listen to a specific MongoDB collection to have each entry as a message in a kafka topic.
This works fine with the following kafka connect configuration:

```
{
  "name": "mongo-source-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.hosts": "192.168.0.151:27017",
    "mongodb.name": "mongo",
    "database.whitelist": "database",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "max.batch.size": 2048,
    "poll.interval.ms": 5000,
    "collection.whitelist": "database.collection"
  }
}
```

With this configuration each Kafka message has the id of the original data record from the MongoDB. Now I'm trying to achieve a key transformation to get a specific value from a field inside the JSON document as message key in kafka. The reason for this is that the data should be partitioned using this field.

I already tried the following config for creating a key:

```
{
  "name": "mongo-source-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.hosts": "192.168.0.151:27017",
    "mongodb.name": "mongo",
    "database.whitelist": "database",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "max.batch.size": 2048,
    "poll.interval.ms": 5000,
    "collection.whitelist": "database.collection",
    "transforms":"createKey",
    "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey", 
    "transforms.createKey.fields": "specific-field-in-mongodb-source-record"
  }
}
```

Then I only receive this error in Kafka Connect:

```
[2019-10-10 11:35:44,049] INFO 2048 records sent for replica set 'dev-shard-01', last offset: {sec=1570707340, ord=1, initsync=true, h=-8774414475389548112} (io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnectorTask)
[2019-10-10 11:35:44,050] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-connector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2019-10-10 11:35:44,050] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2019-10-10 11:35:44,050] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.applyWithSchema(ValueToKey.java:85)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.apply(ValueToKey.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:38)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:194)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-10-10 11:35:44,050] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
```

Another configuration I tried is the following:

```
{
  "name": "mongo-source-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.hosts": "192.168.0.151:27017",
    "mongodb.name": "mongo",
    "database.whitelist": "database",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "max.batch.size": 2048,
    "poll.interval.ms": 5000,
    "collection.whitelist": "database.collection",
    "transforms": "unwrap,insertKey,extractKey",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.insertKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.insertKey.fields": "specific-field-in-mongodb-source-record",
    "transforms.extractKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractKey.field": "specific-field-in-mongodb-source-record",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
  }
}
```

This also leads to an error:

```
[2019-10-10 12:27:04,915] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Struct objects supported for [copying fields from value to key], found: java.lang.String
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireStruct(Requirements.java:52)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.applyWithSchema(ValueToKey.java:79)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.apply(ValueToKey.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:38)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:194)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-10-10 12:27:04,915] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
```

Does anyone know if and how I can transform an element of the JSON document out of the MongoDB into the Kafka message key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some more testing, I found a suitable solution.
I turns out that I don't need the third transformation. It's enough to just use the ValueToKey transformation.

For the sake of completeness, here is the working configuration:

```
{
  "name": "mongo-source-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.hosts": "192.168.0.151:27017",
    "mongodb.name": "mongo",
    "database.whitelist": "database",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "max.batch.size": 2048,
    "poll.interval.ms": 5000,
    "collection.whitelist": "database.collection",
    "transforms": "unwrap,insertKey",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"drop",
    "transforms.unwrap.operation.header":"true",
    "transforms.insertKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.insertKey.fields": "specific-field-in-mongodb-source-record",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
  }
}
```